# Routing Error No Route Matches (correct route)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I'm in the process of building an edit form.  I have completed the form and it renders as it should.  When I go to submit the update to the form I get a no route error.  The path to my edit page is for example '/topics/1/bookmarks/1/edit'.  This page loads perfectly fine.  That page contains a partial of the form that will be used to edit the record.  When I select the submit button however it re-routes to '/topics/1/bookmarks/1' and gives me the following:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/topics/1/bookmarks/1"
```

Below are the files that should be of importance let me know if there is something I did not share.  That would be important to view.

## bookmarks_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])

  if @bookmark.update_attributes(params.require(:bookmark).permit(:url, :topic_id, :description))
    flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was updated"
    redirect_to [@topic, @bookmark]
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the Bookmark.  Please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end
```

## config/routes.rb

```
resources :topics do
  resources :bookmarks, only: [:show, :new, :edit]
end
```

## bookmarks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [topic, bookmark] do |f|  %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.label :url %>
  <%= f.text_field :url %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## bookmarks/edit.html.erb

```
 <%= render partial: 'form', locals: {topic: @topic, bookmark: @bookmark} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an update route, which is what actually updates the database. Just change

```
 resources :bookmarks, only: [:show, :new, :edit]
```

to

```
resources :bookmarks, only: [:show, :new, :edit, :update]
```

OR better yet,

```
resources :bookmarks, except: [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

If you have a new action, then you should want a create action too. So, finally:

```
resources :bookmarks, except: [:index, :destroy]
```

Comment: I was wondering if it was that.  It seemed like everything else was correct.  Thank you for your help Ryan